# What is the name of this multiplayer game where a shield can be 'Regraded' into 'Divine'?

Tags: game-identification

[image: screenshot of the game]

I cannot provide any description, since I have nothing to go on other than the screenshot. I tried a google reverse search, but it came up empty.

Screenshot is taken from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvSbt.jpg

Does anyone know which game this is? I know it is not Guild Wars 2 as suggested in the comments of that gallery post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on one of the comments on the Imgur page, and then looking at said game, I think it is **Archeage**. Here is a screenshot I found on Google Images, where the style and UI matches:

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rlb6A-AEtfw/maxresdefault.jpg